# TikZ: atan plot with `rad()`and with `r` in argument

Tags: tikz-pgf

I thought `rad(atan(pi*\x))` and `atan(pi*\x r)` were equivalent. Is that a bug or am I missing something?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

I thought \verb=rad(atan(pi*\x))= and \verb=atan(pi*\x r)= were equivalent. Is that a bug or am I missing something?

\begin{tikzpicture}[samples=200, domain=-2.5:2.5]
   \useasboundingbox (-2.5,-pi/2) rectangle (2.5,pi/2);
   \draw[black] plot (\x,{rad(atan(pi*\x))});
   \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
      \draw[black] plot (\x,{atan(pi*\x r)});
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485060/how-do-i-plot-the-graph-of-arctan-using-tikz-not-using-pgfplots

Comment: @Bibi From mathematical point of view `atan(pi*\x r)` is meaningless because `atan` takes a real number (not an angle) and returns an angle (in degree). The unit transformation must therefore not be performed on the argument, but on the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rad(...)`, `deg(...)` and  `r` just multiplies with `180/pi` or `pi/180`. Obviously it is not the same to do that inside or outside a trig function. Here are some equivalent methodes to do the same:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[samples=200, domain=-2.5:2.5]
\draw[red] plot (\x,{rad(atan(pi*\x))});
\draw[cyan] plot (\x,{atan(pi*\x r)});
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\draw[red] plot (\x,{pi/180*(atan(pi*\x))});
\draw[cyan] plot (\x,{atan(180/pi*pi*\x)});
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\draw[cyan] plot (\x,{atan(deg(pi*\x))});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Five atan functions]